# i need to get the current locale direction in zend_locale , either rtl or ltr

Tags: zend-framework, localization

i need to get the current locale direction in zend_locale
 either rtl or ltr

Answer (score 3):

```
$localeData = Zend_Locale_Data::getList('ar_SA', 'layout'));
echo $localeData['characters'];
```

That will return *right-to-left* or *left-to-right*